# How to chmod without /usr/bin/chmod?

Tags: permissions, executable, chmod, system-recovery

Today I was told a tale by a Unix trainer where the root password got leaked to the students, and one of the fellas removed the execute permission from `/usr/bin/chmod` itself. How do you recover `chmod` in this case and make it executable again? Let's say getting it from an external source or recompiling it is not a preferable option, is there some smart hack that can recover this `chmod` itself?

Note that this happened a long time ago and I'm not looking for a solution for some current problem, just curious about what ways Unix provides us around such an issue.

Comment: Since all the answers provided are equally "right answers" here, I'm not marking any one of them in particular. Thanks to everyone who answered, every answer was educative in some way.

Comment: Note that the "how do I do this without rebooting?" is as important an exercise as "How do I boot a rescue/installation media and fix this?".  In my opinion you need to be able to do both - it might be a job saver some day.

Comment: The same question (and similar answers) exists on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/189627/i-just-did-a-chmod-x-chmod), too.

Comment: @SpellingD Thanks. It's weird reading that thread, like an alternate universe version of this question with only slightly different answers. And someone there answers they've seen the question previously on slideshare, and someone comments on _that one_ that they've seen it on Reddit too!

Comment: Similar: [How can I execute a file without execute permissions?](http://askubuntu.com/q/354342/78223) at AskUbuntu

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' This is not the same as your proposed duplicate. In that question, the whole directory was changed, no executable file remains to execute any action. Here, all executable files are available **except** chmod. The solutions for each problem are quite different.

Comment: @Isaac Yes, ok, all solutions from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77852/how-to-recover-from-a-chmod-r-000-bin work, but here there are more solutions.

Answer (score 214):

You can run the loader directly, and pass it the command you want to run:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so /bin/chmod +x /bin/chmod
```

Your path to the loader might vary. On a 64-bit system you need to choose the right one based on how `chmod` was compiled; the 64-bit version is named something like `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

Comment: I love any day where I learn something new.

Comment: Thanks. What permissions does ld-linux.so itself have? (I have only cygwin and it doesn't seem to have this file.) Is this an easy way to override the executable permission bit then?

Comment: minor correction: 64 bit libraries are usually under `/lib64`

Comment: On x86 (32-bit) Linux, the dynamic linker must be at exactly the path `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`, on x86-64 (64-bit) Linux, the dynamic linker must be at exactly the path `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.  Both of these are normally symlinks to the correct file, but that exact path is required to be present.

Comment: You hit a homerun with this answer 8-).

Comment: What if those too get their execution bit unset?

Comment: @gerrit If everything gets the execution bit unset, you reboot the system with a live CD and reset the permissions. However, in that case it's probably easier to just reinstall the whole system since who knows what has been borked in the process.

Comment: Note: this is for Linux, not Ubix in general.

Comment: What would happen if you `chmod`'d ld-linux.so?

Comment: @JonathanCallen, not true. NixOS is an example of a Linux-based OS distribution where directories `/lib` and `/lib64` do not even exist.

Comment: @Rotsor I believe NixOS actually has to do something to each binary to use the right linker paths, instead of the hardcoded one.

Comment: This doesn't work if the filesystem is [mounted with noexec](http://serverfault.com/questions/72356/how-useful-is-mounting-tmp-noexec). As it should!

Comment: @AndresRiofrio Why on Earth would `/`, `/lib`, `/bin` or `/usr/bin` be mounted noexec? Your linked question is about `/tmp` which is a different beast entirely.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I think it's because I was trying to execute another program in /tmp using this technique.

Comment: That one was brilliant man :)

Comment: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 , /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 are other path alternatives. If not, use "locate ld-linux" to find it out.

Answer (score 112):

The `chmod` utility relies on the `chmod()` system call (see `man 2 chmod`).  So you could do this with a few lines of C, or just about any other language that has a wrapper around it (which would be most of them).  Very few *nix systems are going to lack a C compiler and a perl interpreter; most linux distros require the later to work.

```
perl -e 'chmod 0755, "foobar.file"'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's sweet. I just tried it out in Perl and it worked.

Comment: Re: "most linux distros require the [perl interpreter] to work": Really? Can you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: @ruakh I would say this is rather true for `python`.

Comment: @ruakh, on Debian-based systems the perl-base package is marked as essential.  Not having perl-base will make the package manager pretty unhappy.  There are a large number of other essential/important tools like adduser that require perl, and are installed in an absolute bare-bones setup.

Comment: @ruakh The reason it is more true of perl than anything else is that perl 5 was around during linux's infancy, while (eg) python 2 was not.  It is kind of the original "dynamically typed, object oriented interpreted" language.  So *in general* the 3 most fundamental languages in the linux world would be 1) C, 2) bash, and 3) perl.  Python has probably eclipsed it in popularity in recent years, but it is just not as historically relevant and thus less likely to be essential -- although in reality both of them are usually available anyway.

Comment: @goldilocks: I didn't mean "as opposed to Python" (since you didn't mention Python); I meant "as opposed to C"!

Comment: @ruakh: Because most distos are binary based -- you don't need a C compiler, because everything is already compiled.  However, you need bash to run the shell scripts, and if perl is fundamental, you need a perl interpreter too.  So, eg., a default fedora or ubuntu install will probably include perl, but not gcc. Of course, C is the ground of everything (perl, python, and bash are written in C) but there does not need to be any C code at all on a running system, because it's all been compiled.

Comment: @goldilocks: Interesting! The Single Unix Specification does mark `cc` as "LEGACY" (and therefore optional), but I didn't realize that Linux distros were actually taking it up on that. :-P (Of course, it doesn't list `perl` at all, even as an optional utility.)

Comment: @ruakh: I just stumbled across this old thread and thought I’d comment that ISTR that, about 20 years ago, Sun Microsystems (subsequently acquired by Oracle) was distributing SunOS and Solaris without a C compiler because they wanted to sell you theirs.  They claimed that this was to decrease the price they charged to low-end users in non-development environments, and of course that meant that developers paid more (or downloaded gcc).

Answer (score 76):

Some systems also have `busybox` installed in which case you may run:

```
busybox chmod +x /bin/chmod
```

Since you were asking for hacks, I just thought of another one:

```
mv /bin/chmod /bin/chmod.orig
cp -a /bin/chown /bin/chmod
```

Now you have a `/bin/chmod` that's executable but it's actually `chown` (i.e. some other binary). Now all we have to do is overwrite it with the original binary.

```
dd if=/bin/chmod.orig of=/bin/chmod
```

It keeps the +x flag so you just stole the +x of another file for this one.

Of course, if all those alternative binaries (including the loader, perl, python, gcc et cetera) were chmod -x, fixing it from a rescue system may be the only option.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `cat` instead of `dd`?

Comment: Yes... I ended up using `dd` because at first I thought it may need `conv=notrunc` or similar to prevent replacing the file entirely, but it does work with most commands that write files after all (including `cat`, `cp`, ...).

Comment: great hack, really clever

Comment: +1, but why tamper with an existing system file at all?  Why not just do `cp /bin/tr /bin/newchmod && cp /bin/chmod /bin/newchmod`?  It seems that you don't need to specify any options to `cp`.  (I chose `tr` because it's a small file with a short, easy-to-type name; obviously, any executable file, such as `/bin/chown`, will work.)

Comment: @G-Man, good point, might be less confusing that way for package managers that track files by timestamps or something.

Answer (score 51):

Easy. What you can do is prepare some other executable file, and then `cp chmod` over it.

```
 $ cp /bin/ls chmod
 $ cp /bin/chmod .
```

The first `cp` creates a file called `chmod` with executable permissions, but which is really the `ls` executable. The second `cp` populates this file with the binary code of `chmod`, while preserving the execute permissions of the target file (because we did not specify any options to carry over permissions of the source file).

---

Another approach is to use the `install` utility which is a glorified copying program which can set permissions in one step. (See the `-m` argument.)

```
$ install -m a+x /bin/chmod .
$ ./chmod # executes
```

The `install` program isn't part of the Unix specification, but it is found in BSD, and in GNU Coreutils. Both support the `-m` option with chmod-like syntax, both symbolic and octal.

Comment: I think this is the simplest and neatest solution here, tested on my Cygwin too, have an upboat.

Comment: Just make sure you're not inside /bin when you do this, or the first step will overwrite the real chmod.

Comment: +1 for `install`. So many solutions. :)

Comment: Best solution, all you need to know is that `cp` doesn't necessarily copy file attributes, it can copy only the content (but you can tell it to copy the attributes too).

Answer (score 16):

First things off the top of my head,

- Boot from any other source (network book, cd, etc.) and use the chmod on that source to set the permissions.
- Write a tiny C program to change the permissions.
- Write a perl script (ruby, php, python, etc.) to change the permissions

`/usr/bin/chmod` is just making a system call to change the permissions, you can make that system call yourself in any number of ways.

Answer (score 14):

This is hackier than any of the other answers
(with the possible exception of the `ld-linux.so` answer,
which is a *really clever* hack),
but may be more adaptable to other problems
(especially if you fall into a time vortex
and travel back to a Land Before Perl™).

1. For safety, copy `/bin/chmod` to a safe place:

   ```
   cd
   cp /bin/chmod .
   ```
2. Do `echo chmod | cpio -oc > chmod.cpio`
   This creates a `cpio` archive (not unlike a `tar` archive) containing `chmod`. 
   The `-c` option specifies that the file metadata is written in hex
   (i.e., in ASCII).
3. `vi chmod.cpio`
   You’ll see something like

   ```
   0707010005DBFD000081A4000303E9000302010000000155C64D6E0000C01D000068E70000C361…chmod^@…
                      ↑↑↑
   ```

   followed by a mixture of control characters, standard ASCII characters,
   and extended ASCII characters.  Note that 0644 = 0x1A4 and 0755 = 0x1ED. 
   Find the `1A4` (starting at the 20th character position)
   and change it to `1ED`.  Save and exit.

   - If you have a hex editor or something similar,
     it might be better to use that to avoid the risk
     that `vi` will contaminate the binary executable code in the file. 
     But I tried this with `vi`, and it seemed to work OK.
4. `cpio -i < chmod.cpio`
   You now have a copy of `chmod` in your directory, protected 755.

Other archive programs may have similar capabilities. 
In particular, `cpio` is old and may be deprecated;
if you don’t have it, look for `pax`.

Comment: This made me chuckle, nice little hack

Answer (score 10):

Or even easier - use `setfacl` which is often present on modern systems:

1. Set executable permission for user:

   ```
   # setfacl -m u::rx /bin/chmod
   ```
2. Now use the now executable binary to set its own permissions back to the original ones (i.e. for all users)

   ```
   # chmod +x /bin/chmod
   ```
3. Drop extended ACL entries - optional, since there might have been a good reason why they were there in the first place.

   ```
   # setfacl -b /bin/chmod
   ```

Note, that `setfacl` can be used on a filesystem that doesn't support ACLs as well.

Comment: this is a cool trick, but you may want to explain what you are doing, and how it works.

Answer (score 7):

`rsync` can also be used to change the file's permissions

```
# rsync /bin/chmod /tmp/chmod --chmod=ugo+x
# ls -al /tmp/chmod
  -rwxr-x--- 1 root root 52000 Sep  6 15:13 /tmp/chmod
#
```

Answer (score 5):

Pipe the contents of chmod into an already executable file

```
cp /usr/bin/executable_file ~/executable_file
cat /usr/bin/chmod > ~/executable_file
~/executable_file +x file_to_be_executed.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `setfacl`:

```
setfacl -m u::rwx /bin/chmod
```

Easy/ Lazy Method ;)

```
rpm -qf /bin/chmod        # gets package name, coreutils
yum reinstall coreutils -y          # :D
```

Test Results:

```
[root@h1 ~]# ll /bin/chmod 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 58656 Mar 15  2019 /bin/chmod
[root@h1 ~]# chmod 444 /bin/chmod 
[root@h1 ~]# ll /bin/chmod 
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 58656 Mar 15  2019 /bin/chmod
[root@h1 ~]# yum reinstall coreutils
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package coreutils.x86_64 0:8.22-24.el7 will be reinstalled
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

======================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                      Arch                                      Version                                           Repository                                             Size
======================================================================================================================================================================================================
Reinstalling:
 coreutils                                    x86_64                                    8.22-24.el7                                       rhel-7-server-rpms                                    3.3 M

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================================================================================================
Reinstall  1 Package

Total download size: 3.3 M
Installed size: 14 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
coreutils-8.22-24.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                               | 3.3 MB  00:00:01     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : coreutils-8.22-24.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                       1/1 
  Verifying  : coreutils-8.22-24.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                       1/1 

Installed:
  coreutils.x86_64 0:8.22-24.el7                                                                                                                                                                      

Complete!
[root@h1 ~]# ll /bin/chmod 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 58656 Mar 15  2019 /bin/chmod
[root@h1 ~]#
```