# What to do when you removed execute permission from some system binaries or libraries?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

It seems I removed executability from system binaries, resulting in loads of `Permission denied`. Do I have to force reboot into host's rescue mode or is there something else I can do while I'm still connected via SSH ? I'm sure forcibly rebooting will cause data loss.

```
root@rautamiekka:~# find / '(' -iname '*.vpk' -o -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.inf' -o -iname '*.bsp' -o -iname '*.so' -o -iname '*.image' -o -iname '*.cfg' -o -iname '*.swf' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.dds' -o -iname '*.cur' -o -iname '*.vfont' -o -iname '*.tga' -o -iname '*.ico' -o -iname '*.icns' -o -iname '*.db' -o -iname '*.cache' -o -iname '*.rad' -o -iname '*.dylib' -o -iname '*.mp3' -o -iname '*.sfk' -o -iname '*.vmf' -o -iname '*.vmt' -o -iname '*.3ds' -o -iname '*.dxf' -o -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.scr' -o -iname '*.lst' -o -iname '*.vdf' -o -iname '*.gam' -o -iname '*.dsp' -o -iname '*.nut' -o -iname '*.ekv' -o -iname '*.rc' -o -iname '*.raw' -o -iname '*.nav' -o -iname '*.manifest' -o -iname '*.vbf' -o -iname '*.kv' -o -iname '*.vfe' -o -iname '*.doc' -o -iname '*.flt' -o -iname '*.1' -o -iname '*.pak' -o -iname '*.asi' -o -iname '*.xml' -o -iname '*.6' -o -iname '*.lua' -o -iname '*.res' -o -iname '*.ttf' -o -iname '*.mix' -o -iname '*.wav' -o -iname '*.vcs' -o -iname '*.vtf' -o -iname '*.exe' -o -iname '*.cab' -o -iname '*.dll' ')' -executable -type f -exec chmod -v a-x '{}' ';'
mode of `/usr/lib/monodoc/browser.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.8.atk-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.8.atk-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.6.gdk-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.6.gdk-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.8.glib-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.8.glib-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.8.gtk-dotnet/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.8.gtk-dotnet.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.10.gtk-dotnet/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.10.gtk-dotnet.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.10.glib-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.10.glib-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.6.pango-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.6.pango-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.6.glib-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.6.glib-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.4.atk-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.4.atk-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/mono-service/2.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/mono-service.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/mono-service/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/mono-service.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.6.gtk-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.6.gtk-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.10.gdk-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.10.gdk-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.8.gtk-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.8.gtk-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.10.gtk-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.10.gtk-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.4.gdk-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.4.gdk-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.10.glade-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.10.glade-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.10.atk-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.10.atk-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.4.gtk-dotnet/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.4.gtk-dotnet.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.6.atk-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.6.atk-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.6.gtk-dotnet/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.6.gtk-dotnet.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.8.gdk-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.8.gdk-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.8.pango-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.8.pango-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.8.glade-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.8.glade-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.6.glade-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.6.glade-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.4.gtk-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.4.gtk-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.4.glade-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.4.glade-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.4.glib-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.4.glib-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.4.pango-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.4.pango-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.2.10.pango-sharp/0.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/policy.2.10.pango-sharp.dll' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/3.5/xbuild.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/mono-configuration-crypto/4.0/mono-configuration-crypto.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/al.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/xbuild.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mcs.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/ilasm.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mkbundle.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/resgen.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/monop.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/wsdl.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gacutil.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mono-service.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/monolinker.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/RabbitMQ.Client.Apigen.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mdoc.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/genxs.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/xsd.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/al.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/secutil.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/dtd2rng.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/httpcfg.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/sqlsharp.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/xbuild.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/svcutil.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/macpack.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/disco.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mconfig.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mono-api-diff.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mono-shlib-cop.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/permview.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mono-cil-strip.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/ccrewrite.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/ilasm.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mkbundle.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/installvst.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/culevel.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/dtd2xsd.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/resgen.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/monop.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/wsdl.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/caspol.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/setreg.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/sqlmetal.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/gacutil.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/browsercaps-updater.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mono-api-info.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/csharp.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/sgen.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mozroots.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mono-service.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/soapsuds.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/monolinker.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mod.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/signcode.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/installutil.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/makecert.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/lc.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/dmcs.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/sn.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mono-xmltool.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/chktrust.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/cert2spc.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/certmgr.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/pdb2mdb.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/RabbitMQ.Client.Apigen.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/genxs.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/xsd.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/ictool.exe' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/plugins/dropin.cache' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libdeploy.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libj2gss.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libavplugin.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libunpack.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libinstrument.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/liblcms.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjdwp.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libmlib_image.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libsaproc.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libdcpr.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libdecora_sse.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpt.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjavafx_font_freetype.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libfxplugins.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libprism_sw.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjfxwebkit.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjpeg.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libj2pcsc.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libawt.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libglass.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libsplashscreen.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjavafx_font_pango.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjsdt.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libj2pkcs11.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjavafx_iio.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjavafx_font.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libsctp.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjaas_unix.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjavafx_font_t2k.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libgstreamer-lite.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjava_crw_demo.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjfxmedia.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_headless.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libdt_socket.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libkcms.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libprism_common.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libt2k.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjsound.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libattach.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libmanagement.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjsig.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libprism_es2.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libhprof.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjfr.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libsunec.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjsoundalsa.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jvm.hprof.txt' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/missioncontrol/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807/eclipse_1502.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/missioncontrol/libcairo-swt.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/amd64/libjawt.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/visualvm/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk16/linux-amd64/libprofilerinterface.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/visualvm/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk15/linux-amd64/libprofilerinterface.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/usr/bin/cpp-4.6' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/lib/klibc-bhN-zLH5wUTKSCGch2ba2xqTtLE.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
mode of `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
#Other lines telling X was removed. Then ...
#§find: `chmod': Permission denied§ many times.

#It seems removing X from some SO files caused this. I didn't think that would cause problems, but it did.
#mode of `/lib/klibc-bhN-zLH5wUTKSCGch2ba2xqTtLE.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
#mode of `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
#mode of `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
#mode of `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
#mode of `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)

root@rautamiekka:~# find / '(' -iname '*.vpk' -o -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.inf' -o -iname '*.bsp' -o -iname '*.so' -o -iname '*.image' -o -iname '*.cfg' -o -iname '*.swf' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.dds' -o -iname '*.cur' -o -iname '*.vfont' -o -iname '*.tga' -o -iname '*.ico' -o -iname '*.icns' -o -iname '*.db' -o -iname '*.cache' -o -iname '*.rad' -o -iname '*.dylib' -o -iname '*.mp3' -o -iname '*.sfk' -o -iname '*.vmf' -o -iname '*.vmt' -o -iname '*.3ds' -o -iname '*.dxf' -o -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.scr' -o -iname '*.lst' -o -iname '*.vdf' -o -iname '*.gam' -o -iname '*.dsp' -o -iname '*.nut' -o -iname '*.ekv' -o -iname '*.rc' -o -iname '*.raw' -o -iname '*.nav' -o -iname '*.manifest' -o -iname '*.vbf' -o -iname '*.kv' -o -iname '*.vfe' -o -iname '*.doc' -o -iname '*.flt' -o -iname '*.1' -o -iname '*.pak' -o -iname '*.asi' -o -iname '*.xml' -o -iname '*.6' -o -iname '*.lua' -o -iname '*.res' -o -iname '*.ttf' -o -iname '*.mix' -o -iname '*.wav' -o -iname '*.vcs' -o -iname '*.vtf' -o -iname '*.exe' -o -iname '*.cab' -o -iname '*.dll' ')' -executable -type f -print
-bash: /usr/bin/find: Permission denied

root@rautamiekka:~# which find
-bash: /usr/bin/which: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
root@rautamiekka:~# chmod
-bash: /bin/chmod: Permission denied
root@rautamiekka:~# ls
-bash: /usr/bin/ionice: Permission denied
root@rautamiekka:~# reboot
-bash: /sbin/reboot: Permission denied
root@rautamiekka:~# poweroff
-bash: /sbin/poweroff: Permission denied


root@rautamiekka:~# echo

root@rautamiekka:~# echo $
$
root@rautamiekka:~# echo $
$_                            $BASH_SUBSHELL                $HISTSIZE                     $LS_COLORS                    $RANDOM
$BASH                         $BASH_VERSINFO                $HOME                         $MACHTYPE                     $_scp_path_esc
$BASH_ALIASES                 $BASH_VERSION                 $HOSTNAME                     $MAIL                         $SECONDS
$BASH_ARGC                    $COLUMNS                      $HOSTTYPE                     $MAILCHECK                    $SHELL
$BASH_ARGV                    $COMP_WORDBREAKS              $IFS                          $OPTERR                       $SHELLOPTS
$BASH_CMDS                    $DERBY_HOME                   $J2REDIR                      $OPTIND                       $SHLVL
$BASH_COMMAND                 $DIRSTACK                     $J2SDKDIR                     $OSTYPE                       $SSH_CLIENT
$BASH_COMPLETION              $EUID                         $JAVA_HOME                    $PATH                         $SSH_CONNECTION
$BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR   $GROUPS                       $LANG                         $PIPESTATUS                   $SSH_TTY
$BASH_COMPLETION_DIR          $__grub_script_check_program  $LESSCLOSE                    $PPID                         $TERM
$BASH_LINENO                  $HISTCMD                      $LESSOPEN                     $PS1                          $UID
$BASHOPTS                     $HISTCONTROL                  $LINENO                       $PS2                          $USER
$BASHPID                      $HISTFILE                     $LINES                        $PS4                          $XDG_SESSION_COOKIE
$BASH_SOURCE                  $HISTFILESIZE                 $LOGNAME                      $PWD
```

Comment: Can you try something like `bash -c <command>` ?

Comment: @AshishKulkarni: `root@rautamiekka:~# bash -c pwd`
`-bash: /bin/bash: Permission denied`

Comment: @AshishKulkarni: OP edited.

Comment: I'm afraid there's not much to do at this point. I guess `echo` is also out of the question?

Comment: @AshishKulkarni: OP updated.

Comment: is `sh` working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15871/discussion-between-ashish-kulkarni-and-rautamiekka).

Comment: you had a nice `find` filter defined but then used the `-executable` option.. which would then catch any executable files irrelevant of the previously defined filter.

Comment: @fduff: So do it with `-and -executable` ?

Comment: @AshishKulkarni: No, `sh` and `/bin/sh` both give the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what directories were affected -- looks like you do -- you can run, e.g.:

```
chmod -R 755 /usr/bin
```

`-R` is recursive.  This should be fine for everything in a `bin` directory.  If `chmod` itself is affected, you could [try this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83862/how-to-chmod-without-usr-bin-chmod) on it, or else boot the box with a live CD and use that.