# executed "chmod 666 ld-2.17.so" - how can i recover?

Tags: centos, permissions, dynamic-linking

While trying to learn about how `ld-2.17.so` works to change the permission of `chmod` executable itself, and thought if i can change the permission of `ld-2.17.so` itself.

I ran `chmod 666 ld-2.17.so` in a test centos 7 machine and after it I can't run any command since most of the commands use `ld-2.17.so`.

I have already read this answer, [Recovering from removing execute permission from ld-linux.so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416196/recovering-from-removing-execute-permission-from-ld-linux-so)

It gives a very general answer but not a specific solution.
Is there anywhere in Centos7 i can find `ld-2.17.so` cache to recover `/lib64/ld-2.17.so` permission back to normal?

**Edit:** I have tried to `scp` this file, `/lib64/ld-2.17.so` from other machine to affected machine, but I get permission denied error.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an executable file you can write to, you could copy the contents of `ld.so` to that file using bash's `read`:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r  line; do printf "%s\0" "$line"; done > executable-file < /lib64/ld-2.17.so
```

Example:

```
bash-4.2$ ll foo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 muru muru 29K Aug 23 13:02 foo*
bash-4.2$ while IFS= read -d '' -r  line; do printf "%s\0" "$line"; done > foo < /lib64/ld-2.17.so
bash-4.2$ ./foo
Usage: ld.so [OPTION]... EXECUTABLE-FILE [ARGS-FOR-PROGRAM...]
You have invoked `ld.so', the helper program for shared library executables.
...
```

Then you can use it to  run `chmod`:

```
bash-4.2$ ./foo /bin/chmod
/bin/chmod: missing operand
Try '/bin/chmod --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Thankk you muru. That's really helpful.
Could you please suggest if i don't have any sample executable available is there any unused executable that I can use from within Linux? One more question, how do you know bash's `read` doesn't used dynamic libraries.
thank you

Comment: @MaverickD the assumption here is that you already have a running shell from before you messed up `ld.so`. If you don't, and you don't have a statically compiled shell (like busybox) available, you have to reboot and use recovery methods, plain and simple. As for sample executables, pick any except `chmod` and then reinstall that command later once you have fixed `ld.so`. (or you can save the contents to a different file, using the same `read` method)