# why while loop works from terminal if ld-2.17.so have no executable permission?

Tags: bash, chmod

In my previous question, [executed "chmod 666 ld-2.17.so" - how can i recover?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464289/executed-chmod-666-ld-2-17-so-how-can-i-recover) I asked if I change `ld-2.17.so` permission to read, how can I recover it back, since it won't allow me to execute anything at all that requires these libraries ?

And I got the answer as follows,

> If you have an executable file you can write to, you could copy the
>   contents of ld.so to that file using bash's read:
>
> `while IFS= read -d '' -r  line; do printf "%s\0" "$line"; done >
>   executable-file < /lib64/ld-2.17.so`

I tried it, and it worked. 
But what I am confused about is why this `while` loop works if `/bin/bash` itself requires `lib64/ld-2.17.so` library, as can be seen as follows,

```
ldd /bin/bash
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc54dee000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f6fb9bbe000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6fb99ba000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6fb95f6000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055ec142f5000)
```

Can someone please tell me why `bash` code worked from terminal without the `/lib64/ld-2.17.so`?
Does that also mean that I can also create an empty executable file using `bash` from terminal even if `/lib64/ld-2.17.so` has no permissions?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r line; do 
    printf "%s\0" "$line"
done > executable-file < /lib64/ld-2.17.so
```

only uses shell built-ins, so it doesn’t need to start new processes. The recovery scenario assumes that you already have a shell running; since it’s already running, its permissions on disk, and those of its libraries, no longer matter.

You wouldn’t be able to start a new shell under these circumstances, but nothing currently running is affected by the changed permissions.

If the file you’re trying to read from has *no* permissions, this will only work if you’re in a root shell; otherwise the redirection from `ld-2.17.so` will fail since you can’t read from an unreadable file unless you’re root. (I’m ignoring SELinux etc. here.)