# What happens if I change chmod permissions to rrr

Tags: permissions, root, chmod

I want to try to change `/bin/chmod` permissions file to `rrr` but afraid to loose my machine. What happens next if I change them?

Comment: The permissions of which files, exactly?

Comment: Fixed it in edit. The permission of `which chmod` itslef

Comment: Possible duplicate of “[How to chmod without /usr/bin/chmod?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83862/80216)”

Answer (score 2):

If you remove execute permissions from the *chmod* binary, then all shell scripts (including *Makefile*s!) that try to execute it will get an error when they try. This includes countless administrative and installation scripts. Your system will fail to work correctly in many unforeseen ways.

Actual programs that call the Unix syscall directly instead of *exec*’ing another program to do their dirty work for them will be unaffected. But this is little consolation, and your system will still be seriously broken and potentially damaged.

To revert, you would have to write an actual program that can access the real syscall, which means using something like C or Perl, not the shell.

Comment: yes it's okay, but this is `chmod`, will I be able to revert it somehow?

Comment: @VitaliPom Do you understand the difference between executing a program and calling the kernel syscall?

Comment: Now I do yes after reading the answers

Comment: Actually, there are several ways of getting back, from toybox to `install`.  But that's properly another question.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do that? I don't see any potentially worthwhile point to that.

You won't lose your machine from doing that, but you'll make it a little harder to change permissions (anybody who'll want to do that will have to find - or make - another program that performs the `chmod(2)` system call.

I would recommend against doing that, and if you have done so (by accident) I would hurry to find another tool that could undo the change.

Comment: oh, so you're saying I'll have to write a little bit more complex program similar to `chmod` to revert the changes to chmod itself (like something in C that revert the metadata settings to the original file itself (aka `chmod`).

Comment: There are many, many possibilities. You could archive your `chmod` binary, e.g. using `pax`, `tar`, or `cpio`, then change the permission metadata inside the archive using a hex editor, then extract it again. Or, just run `ruby -e 'File.chmod(0755, "/bin/chmod"'`, or the Perl, Python, PHP, or Tcl equivalent.