# How to change file permission without chmod?

Tags: permissions, chmod

Our college assigned us a homework for Unix.

We have to change the permission of a newly created file to `222` without using `chmod`.

> Decrease the file permission by "222" [Do not use chmod command]:

Personally to me, I can use Ruby:

```
ruby -e "File.chmod(0222, File.join(Dir.pwd, 'F2'))"
```

But these kinds of solutions are probably not allowed.

Also, here I got the question:
[How to chmod without /usr/bin/chmod?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83862/how-to-chmod-without-usr-bin-chmod)

But the answers were a bit different. They were discussing about restoring the deleted `chmod` binary.

How can I change the permission of a file without `chmod`?

Comment: "these kinds of solutions are probably not allowed" Ask and find out.

Comment: Well, I am not in the college, and I have to submit it tomorrow! Even no programming languages are allowed to do this... Is there any chmod alternative that will run on Unix?

Comment: you could use `stat` to get the current perms, then "decrease" them by 222 (e.g. by AND-ing them with "not 222"), then `install -m "$newperms" "$origfile" "$tempfile"` and `mv -f $tempfile "$origfile"` (but this will break any hard links)

Comment: That's helpful. But it doesn't seem clean to get the permission, deduct the permission by 0222, then change the permission. But we have to deal with that!

Comment: @S.Goswami [ilkkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537428/116858) contains all the hints you need. Note that you are probably not being asked to change the permissions on any existing files (you don't seem to quote that bit verbatim though), only on files that you create.

Comment: if this question is only about creating new files in your shell, then you need to set the `umask`.  As this is homework, I won't give you an exact answer, but that ought to be enough to point you in the right direction.   If you solve the problem using this, please write it up as an answer.

Comment: This is not about creating files. I am aware of the umask command. But the file has to be created with cat command (and it will be called F2), which is also tricky, and I did that... Then there's the part quoted in the question. Also, everything has to be done on Unix. I am using DragonFly BSD for that reason... I am actually writing a script for the solution on my Arch Linux system. And then I will test that on the minimal DragonFly BSD installation and then write up the confirmed answer.

Comment: I created a file called F2 and changed the permission to 777 for test. I then ran this: `install -m $(expr $(stat F2 | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | sed '4q;d' | sed s/[^0-9]//g) - 222) F2 F2_cp && mv F2_cp F2 -f` This worked on a GNU/Linux system. On Unix however, stat shows results differently... So it doesn't work!

Comment: Aren't there any other straight forward ways to change permission just without chmod that will work on Unix?

Comment: Let me wait and ask our professors... :D

Comment: @S.Goswami If you are aware of the `umask` command, then I suggest that you read its manual again. You have the solution to you issue, you just haven't put the pieces together in the right order (literally).

Comment: It's undefined what is allowed and what isn't. You have to use chmod syscall, no matter what. Or it would be a word game.

Answer (score 3):

Note that your specification explicitly talks about **newly created files**. You couldn't even use `chmod` to change that, since a new file would have some set of permissions when created, before you could use `chmod` on them.

Also, while that Ruby script doesn't run the `chmod` command/utility, it does use the same underlying system call, so it's practically the same thing. If it were me, I wouldn't allow that.

Without giving out the full answer, I'd suggest looking at what [the man page for `open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) says about the permissions of the created file:

> The mode argument specifies the file mode bits be applied when
>                 a new file is created.  This argument must be supplied when
>                 `O_CREAT` or `O_TMPFILE` is specified in flags; if neither `O_CREAT`
>                 nor `O_TMPFILE` is specified, then mode is ignored.  The
>                 effective mode is modified by the process's umask in the usual
>                 way: in the absence of a default ACL, the mode of the created
>                 file is `(mode & ~umask)`.  Note that this mode applies only to
>                 future accesses of the newly created file; the `open()` call
>                 that creates a read-only file may well return a read/write
>                 file descriptor.
>
> The following symbolic constants are provided for mode:
>
> `S_IRWXU`  `00700` user (file owner) has read, write, and execute
>                          permission
>
> [etc.]

Also note that the part you  quoted said to "decrease the permissions **by** 222", not **to** 222. That's also important regarding the function I'm thinking of.

Since it was already mentioned in the comments

> I'm thinking of `umask`, which limits the permissions of newly-created files. It should be a standard feature, and should work the same in Linux and in DragonFly.

Of course, all of this is just my interpretation of that assignment. There's no way for any of us here to know for sure what the correct answer is in the opinion of your teacher/professor, especially since sometimes the answers given by professors are not even the correct ones.

Comment: I don't see this matching up with the manpage of open in DragonFly BSD...

Comment: Yep, the [DragonFly BSD man page](https://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=open&section=2) says: "... In this case open() and openat() require a third argument mode_t mode, and the file is created with mode mode as described in chmod(2) and modified by the process' umask value (see umask(2))."