# Can `chmod -R 777 /bin` be recovered from?

Tags: chmod, system-recovery

I know that [`chmod -R 777 /` is extremely destructive](https://serverfault.com/q/364677/313521), and I know that a [`chmod -R 000 /bin` can be recovered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77852/135943) by using an *additional disk*, but I'm wondering about `chmod -R 777 /bin`.

If I have a root shell, but no additional disk mounted from a healthy VM, can I recover this system?

---

(This question is for learning purposes as the actual box is not mine, nor was the mistake, and the box is already planned to be rebuilt.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As argued in the response you link, it depends on your definition of "recover" (i.e. do you still trust a binary after it was potentially changed by anybody on the system, which may be "I guess I'm ok" for your private desktop machine but much much less so on a multi-user company system).

Looking at my box, `/bin` has a manageable number of files that aren't 0755 or symlinks:

```
ls -l /bin/ | grep -v '^-rwxr-xr-x' | grep -v '^l' | wc -l
35
```

and that's mostly because they're setgid or setuid. So in principle, you could `chmod 0755 /bin/*` and manually fix the permissions on those 30, 40 binaries, if you still have root access. (`su` and `sudo` won't work until their proper permissions are restored.)

But for practical purposes, that still means you need a "clean" machine somewhere for comparison purposes, but you don't need to mount its drive.

(Come to think of it, I don't think wrong permissions on the binaries should stop the package manager from working, so you could conceivably try reinstalling every package that has something in `/bin`, but probably most everything has a dependency on something in `/bin`, so you might end up removing and reinstalling all packages.)

Answer (score 1):

On my mint system all the files in /bin are 0755 except  fusermount, mount, ping, ping6, and su, which are 04755.

0755 is a reasonable permission mask for a shared executable. Which executables are setuid will depend very much on your system's security policies.

Trying:

```
chmod -R 0755 /bin && chmod  04755 /bin/{{,fuser}mount,ping{,6},su}
```

(as root) can do little harm at this point (setting setuid root on anything is a potential vulnerability).